# Docker for windowsが起動できない

Tags: windows, docker

Docker for Windows をインストールし、Docker Desktopを起動しても、添付画像のように、「Cannot enable Hyper -V Service」と表示され、起動ができません。

また、Hyper-Vを以下の記事を参考にセットアップしているのですが、Powershellで添付画像のようなエラーが出ます。

[Windows10 Pro上でHyper-Vコンテナーを使い始める手順 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/anikundesu/items/90a7706b434daed5e266)

**エラーメッセージ:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Windowsの機能とプログラムでHyper-Vを有効化しているはずですが、他に起動に必要な条件があるのでしょうか？
初心者で手落ちがあるかもしれませんが、よろしくご教授お願い致します。

環境
Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Hyper-V の設定変更後、Windows は再起動していますか？

Comment: BIOSで仮想化の設定が有効になってますか？

Comment: どのようなことをすると（どのように起動すると）エラーが出ているのでしょうか？また質問者さんが参考先と同じようにやっているつもりでも、ひとつでも間違うとうまく行かない可能性があります、リンクだけで済ませるのではなく、できる限り詳細な手順をお書きいただいたほうが、回答がつきやすくなると思います

Answer (score 1):

BIOSの項目で有効にしなければいけないものがあります。

下記リンクが質問者さんと同様のエラーについてのものです。

[Cannot enable hyper-v service - Docker Desktop for Windows - Docker Community Forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-enable-hyper-v-service/94086)

> Try to enable virtualization in BIOS.

> Enabling virtualization worked for me, thanks mate

> Enabling virtualization from BIOS worked out for me as well. Thanks!

というように上記リンクにそれで解決したという旨がたくさんのっています。

日本語だと下記のようなページがBIOSについて言及しているのが、見つかりました。

[Windows 10で仮想化プラットフォーム「Hyper-V」を有効にする：Tech TIPS - ＠IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1806/25/news026.html)

一方質問者さんが、参考になさっているページにはBIOSの記述がみつからないように思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
頂いたURLを参考にBIOSからvirtualizationをEnableにしました。
しかし、再起動後もHyper-Vのチェックボックスがオンになっているものの同じエラー画面が出てしまいました。
コマンドプロンプトでdocker -Vを打ち込むとVersionが表示されるので、Desktopアプリの問題なのでしょうか。

Comment: ダメでしたか、それは残念です。質問は編集できますので、BIOSを設定した手順等も書いていただけると、別の方が回答しやすいと思います。

Comment: 普通に使えていましたが、Docker Desktopのupdateを行ったら、同じ現象が出ました。紹介されている記事でHyper-Vの設定を確認したところ有効になっています。

Comment: Docker Desktopをアップデートしたあと、Windowsを再起動したところエラーは解消されました。

Answer (score 1):

BIOSの設定をEnableにしてもうまくいかない場合、管理者権限でコマンドプロンプトを起動して

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

を実行して再起動するとうまくいく、と言う記事がありました。[it-swarm.devより](https://www.it-swarm.dev/ja/windows/hyperv%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E5%A0%B1%E5%91%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/959016475/)
これを試されてみてはどうでしょうか。